# Equals button in calculator doing nothing (Android Developer Tools)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I cant really figure out, I am beginner to programming, doing it for about 2 months. I have made calculator for Android, but problem is that equals button does nothing.

Setting up different variables:

```
Button one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,zero,plus,minus,divide,multiply,dot,equals;
ImageButton clear;
TextView result;
String theresult;
```

All buttons except equals just append respective text to variable result.

Here is code of only equal button(created just plus to test, but failed):

```
    equals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equals);
    equals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String expression = String.valueOf(result);

            if(expression.contains("+")){
            String[] numbers = expression.split("\\+");
            String no1 = numbers[0];
            String no2 = numbers[1];

            Double numb1 = Double.valueOf(no1);
            Double numb2 = Double.valueOf(no2);
            Double added = numb1+numb2;

            theresult = String.valueOf(added);
            result.setText(theresult);


            }
        }
    });
```

I have used if here, so that I can use else if to make other operations work. Later on I will use Try-Catch block too. Thank you for your time!

Full code of MainActivity.java

```
package org.example.calc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,zero,plus,minus,divide,multiply,dot,equals;
ImageButton clear;
TextView result;
String theresult;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

    one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.append("1");
        }
    });


    two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.append("2");
        }
    });

    three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
    three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.append("3");
        }
    });

    four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
    four.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.append("4");
        }
    });

    five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
    five.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.append("5");
        }
    });


    six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
    six.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.append("6");
        }
    });


    seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
    seven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.append("7");
        }
    });

    eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
    eight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.append("8");
        }
    });

    nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);
    nine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.append("9");
        }
    });


    zero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zero);
    zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.append("0");
        }
    });

    dot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dot);
    dot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.append(".");
        }
    });


    clear = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.clear);
    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.setText("");
        }
    });


    plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.append("+");
        }
    });

    minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.append("-");
        }
    });

    divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divide);
    divide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.append("/");
        }
    });


    multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
    multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.append("x");
        }
    });


    equals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equals);
    equals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result.getText();
            String expression = String.valueOf(result);

            if(expression.contains("+")){
            String[] numbers = expression.split("\\+");
            String no1 = numbers[0];
            String no2 = numbers[1];

            Double numb1 = Double.valueOf(no1);
            Double numb2 = Double.valueOf(no2);
            Double added = numb1+numb2;

            theresult = String.valueOf(added);
            result.setText(theresult);


            }
        }
    });




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Did you assigned the `TextView` named *result* correctly with `findViewById`? Your current post seems like it was just declaired.

Comment: @hata yes I have assigned it. I have added full code to main post. please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do thus:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String expression = result.getText().toString();
    // Log.d("LOG", expression);

    if(expression.contains("+")){
        (...)
```

Maybe work. No need of using `String.valueOf()`

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from CharSequence to String

Comment: I used cast to string as String expression = (String) result.getText(); but thats crashing.

Comment: @Talpur Sorry, it should be using with `toString()`. Updated my answer.

Comment: I did debugging. It checks the condition at if(expression.contatins("+")), and skips everything inside it. Condition isn't true, i.e. expression doesn't conations +.

Comment: @Talpur Check value of expression by inserting `Log.d("LOG", expression);` just next to the `String expression = (result.getText()).toString();` and see LogCat.

Comment: hey! String expression= result.getText().toString(); worked well :D Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you press your equals button you have to get the value of the textview by result.getText() so that you will get the value of text view and assign it in some string. 
String expression = String.valueOf(result);

Here you are simply using the result in String.valueOf(). Check whether your are getting the correct value or not by debugging or some sort of print statments.

Also post your code completely/reasonable code to avoid more questions so that you will get your answer.

Comment: I did that but again nothing happened. I have added whole code to main post with your suggestion.

Comment: String expression = (String)result.getText();

Comment: I did debugging. It checks the condition at if(expression.contatins("+")), and skips everything inside it. Condition isn't true, i.e. expression doesn't conations +.

Comment: casting to String is throwing exception

Comment: show me the stracktrace. Also try with this String expression= result.getText().toString();

Comment: worked with String expression= result.getText().toString(); Thanks